# How to replicate Photoshop filters and actions into MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, photoshop, photography

How can I use MATLAB to replicate [Photoshop filters and actions](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/20/the-ultimate-collection-of-useful-photoshop-actions/)?  Is there something in the image processing toolbox already that I can use?  Or will I have to start from scratch, research each filter, and make a function for it?

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some filters in the Matlab image processing toolbox. These filters are very complete and well written. And some of the Photoshop filters may be mapped to a function in the toolbox.

However, there is not a one to one mapping between functions in the Matlab image processing toolbox filters and the available Photoshop filters.

To simplify things a lot, you will have to research each filter, and make a function for it, which may or may not be a combination of functions in the Matlab image processing toolbox. Observe that Adobe, the company that makes Photoshop employs several (many) important researchers in image processing and computer vision, and some of these filter will take many years to implement correctly. So making a function for each Photoshop filter may be a monumental task.